# ¿Se usa en español "Pintarse en una esquina"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, coloquialismos

En inglés hay una expresión que dice "to paint yourself/themselves in a corner". Este modismo literalmente significa "pintarse en una esquina" y su significado es bastante gráfico.

Creo que nadie pinta realmente el suelo, pero "fregar" valdría también para explicar el resultado de esta acción. El sentido figurado es que uno empieza a pintar o a fregar y de repente te das cuenta de que te has "encerrado" o arrinconado a ti mismo en una esquina y no puedes salir hasta que el suelo se seque.

[image]

Este modismo se usa para resaltar que una persona orgullosa se arrincona a sí misma en una conversación o discusión. En lugar de admitir un error al principio la persona sigue discutiendo intentando demostrar que no está equivocada, pero en lugar de hacerlo cada vez se arrincona más en una situación de la que es más y mas difícil salir salvando el orgullo.

¿Se usa en español la expresión "pintarse en una esquina"? ¿Hay algún otro modismo similar?

Comment: Creo que [_corner_ en este contexto es más bien "rincón"](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/rincon-y-esquina-2312/). Yo adaptaría la expresión al español como "arrinconarse pintando" o más libremente "seguir pintando hasta arrinconarse". De todas formas, yo diría que esta expresión se usa más bien cuando alguien va tomando malas decisiones que lo van dejando cada vez en peor situación hasta que se queda sin buenas opciones. En español sería "meterse en un callejón sin salida".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión "pintarse en una esquina" así tal cual no me suena para nada en español. Como alternativas, la primera palabra que se me ocurre es la que tú propones:

> **[arrinconar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3lJn79Z)**
>
> 2. tr. Acosar a alguien no dejándole escape. U. m. en sent. fig.

Este verbo se puede usar como pronominal, y así tendríamos ***arrinconarse***, o también se usa como ***quedarse arrinconado***. Luego me puse a buscar otras opciones. Busqué por *encerrar* y vi que una de las acepciones redirigía al siguiente verbo:

> **[encastillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F2bzf3W)**
>
> 5. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Perseverar con tesón, y a veces con obstinación, en su parecer y dictamen, sin atender a razones en contrario.

Esta acepción se parece bastante a lo que comentas, aunque no llega a contener el matiz de llegar a quedarse arrinconado.

Como última opción, una expresión del castellano antiguo que aún hoy se usa en España ([ejemplos](https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl#q=sostenella%20y%20no%20enmendalla&tbm=nws)) y que también se me ha venido a la cabeza al leer tu pregunta:

> **[Sostenella y no enmendalla](http://etimologias.dechile.net/Expresiones/?Sostenella-y-no-enmendalla)** (leído con *l* geminada: *ŀl*)
>
> La expresión define la actitud de quien persiste empecinadamente en
>   errores garrafales, incluso a sabiendas, por orgullo o por mantener
>   las apariencias, aunque el mantener el error cause un daño peor que no
>   mantenerlo, y a ellos se le dice. La forma es la del castellano
>   antiguo (en lugar de "sostenerla y no enmendarla") porque definía la
>   actitud y el concepto del honor de los antiguos hidalgos que, según
>   algunos, una vez habían desenvainado la espada por algún agravio,
>   aunque se hubieran equivocado, no tenían más remedio que sostenerla y
>   usarla hasta el final, so pena de quedar en entredicho.

En visto también en el CORDE que otras posibles formas de usar esta frase son:

- *Defendella y no enmendalla*.
- *Mantenella y no enmendalla*.

Ah, bueno, y ya como sinónimos de *[cabezonería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6QrkS7M)* tenemos:

> [**estarse, mantenerse,** o **seguir,** alguien **en** sus
>   **trece**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aYPXdWU#6UvaSx4)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. Persistir con pertinacia en algo que ha aprendido o empezado a ejecutar.
> 2. locs. verbs. Mantener a todo trance su opinión.

Comment: Me gusta especialmente _sostenella y no enmendalla_. Me recuerda el más castizo _antes partía que doblá_.

Comment: @fedorqui Off-topic, pero tu expresión castiza me recuerda el lema de un viejo partido político argentino: *Se rompe pero no se dobla*. Evidentemente no era una idea nueva cuando lo acuñaron.

Comment: @pablodf76 no me parece offtopic, también parece que hace referencia al hecho de mantenerse firme y rígido ante una determinada situación, y no mostrar flexibilidad.

Comment: La explicación de _sostenella y no enmendalla_ clava lo que yo buscaba para "pintarse en una esquina". Suena muy _raruna_ al ser castellano antiguo, pero desde luego es lo mismo: alguien persiste por orgullo en sus errores y casi quedan más en evidencia todavía y en peor situación. Gracias!